# Django-CMS foreign key on pages showing published and draft pages

Tags: django, django-cms

I have recently upgraded from Django-CMS 2.3.5 to 2.4.1.

Previously I had a model like so:

```
from django.db import models
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
```

In the admin, this would nicely allow me to choose a page to associate with `MyModel`.

Now that I have upgraded, and gone through and pressed "publish draft" on all my pages, the same admin page shows two copies of each page in its selection box - one published and one draft.

Some [further investigation](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/343) has uncovered that the teaser plugin has the following added in its definition to deal with this:

```
    page_link = models.ForeignKey(Page,
        limit_choices_to={'publisher_is_draft': True},
        ...)
```

Similarly, I used to be able to look up page URLs in my views like so:

```
Page.objects.get(reverse_id='update').get_absolute_url()
```

But now I have to use:

```
Page.objects.get(reverse_id='update', publisher_is_draft=False).get_absolute_url()
```

This seems a bit ugly.

Are the `limit_choices_to` and the extra field in the `get` now necessary?  Or is there a cleaner way to only see published pages?  (e.g. I notice that other cms plugins, e.g. link, picture, use foreign keys without a `limit_choices_to` argument.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For better handling of foreign keys to cms pages you need to use PageField instead of ForeignKey

https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.4.3/extending_cms/fields.html

```
from django.db import models
from cms.models.fields import PageField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_page = PageField()
```

When you want to get url for a page by it's reverse_id you need to use the following

```
Page.objects.public().get(reverse_id='update').get_absolute_url()
```

Comment: A further question - do you know if this handles multiple sites for me, or do I need to use: `Page.objects.public().get(reverse_id='update', site=get_current_site(request)).get_absolute_url()` ?

Comment: As I see in the code you need to specify `site` if you use the same `reverse_id` for different pages in different sites.
Also for more details you can see the code of `{% page_id_url %}` template tag https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py#L111